# Primitive Feature Detection to Detect a Black Circle within an Image

Tags: image-processing, matlab, opencv, detection, image-analysis

I am trying to check whether this black circle is exist or not on my images.

[image]

My current approach is like that;

- Hough Circle detection
- Crop the outer roi
- Adaptive threshold

[image]

- count zero pixels
- if ( zero pixels >500 ) 
  black hole exist 
  else 
  black hole does not.

I just want to know is this method useful if this algorithm go for real time check ? if not what kind of methods you could suggest me ?

Here is a image with blackhole

[image]

Here is a image without a blackhole.

[image]

Comment: Could you post images after each step of your current algorithm ? Will the black hole always be centered in the image ? If so, you can crop the image to begin with, which will mean less pixels to analyze, so more time to perform analysis.

Comment: If the both the image and coin sizes keep the same, can you just check the pixel values within a small circle region around the center? Hough detection might be an overkill in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a much simpler method.

The steps I did are:

1. I filtered the image with an [Edge Preserving Filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/76844).
2. I looked the profile of values along the 2 diagonals of the image.

I think once you look at it, it will be easy to build a model.
Let's see the image without the black circle:

[image]

[image]

[image]

From ~150 to ~250 we see mostly a flat zone.

Now, let's see the image with the black circle:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, on the same segment we see 2 levels.

This is a great feature to classify with.

The code is available at my [StackExchange Codes Signal Processing GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q22183` folder).